# Raphael Image URI in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, raphael

I know we can make an image using raphael this way

```
var my_image = paper.image("computer.png", 0, 0, 100, 50)
```

The problem is, when this code is put in /app/assets/javascripts in Rails folder structure, it cannot access the URI since in production, we can only do `asset_path("computer.png")` in the controller or view.

Now, how to trick this problem? which is to obtain the relative URI in the javascript asset file? I was thinking of putting the image as an SVG symbol in the index.html.erb. Since that is a .erb file, we can use `assets_path`. Nah, how to access a symbol using raphael?

Or is there any better solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use gem [`js_assets`](https://github.com/kavkaz/js_assets)

In your application.js

```
//= require app_assets
```

This directive adds the method asset_path in the global scope.

Add to filter files `*.png`. To do this, add initizlizer:

```
# config/initializers/js_assets.rb

JsAssets::List.allow << '*.png'
```

Get the path to the file `app/assets/images/computer.png` in javascript:

```
var path_to_computer = asset_path('computer.png')

// the function will return for development:
// /assets/computer.png
//
// and for production
// /assets/computer-5eb3bb250d5300736006c8944e436e3f.png
```